# Subscribe to multiple observables with one subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it bad practice to subscribe with the same subscription to different observables in the same component? Just in order to unsubscribe them in ngOnDestroy(). Or will the second subscription just override the first one?

```
userSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit(): void {

  this.userSubscription = this.userService.add(user)
    .subscribe(response => {
      ...
    })

  this.userSubscription = this.userService.update(user)
    .subscribe(response => {
      ...
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong thing to do. The subscription to `this.userService.add(user)` will be never unsubscribed. Consider though that, if these Observables are related to http calls performed via the Angular http client, you do not have to worry about unsubscribing, since these Observables per their nature complete after they have emitted once. For more esamples on typical Observable patterns you may want to take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef636c9af19a)

Comment: You should be using forkJoin / zip or any of those operator rxjs have instead

Comment: I would recommend to use the `takeUntil()` operator or as already mentioned the `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 1):

U could use the api add of Subscription like

```
this.userSubscription.add(
  this.userService.add(user)
  .subscribe(response => {
    ...
  })
)
```

then

```
this.userSubscription.add(
  this.userService.update(user)
  .subscribe(response => {
    ...
  })
)
```

and U just need one unsubscribe like u want